# Will Apple offer a discounted replacement for a water damaged iPhone 4S outside of warranty?

Tags: iphone, warranty, applecare, damage

Will Apple offer a discounted replacement for a water damaged iPhone 4S outside of warranty? The water indicators on the outside of the phone have not gone off, but the one inside on the logic board may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will.  I believe, but don't quote me, replacement cost will be $99.  Apple will only deny service if there is catastrophic damage (imagine a phone in 3 pieces), is a counterfeit device or if it is missing parts.  If it is only liquid damage then they will likely offer replacement at that discounted cost.

Comment: Please do try @Oliver, and comment when you have. I strongly believe otherwise.

Comment: @Emil FWIW my source is personal experiencing working as a Genius for 3 years, so I remember policies but am also familiar with how often they can and do change. An old colleague of mine confirmed this about 3 months ago though when my sister had a liquid damaged iPhone with surely a triggered internal LSI. I could very well be wrong though, 3 months is a long time for a policy to stay intact around Apple retail ;)